# node.js - Getting the name of a JSON key from a variable

Tags: json, node.js

So, I would like to edit a key in a JSON file in Node.js, where the key is specified in a variable.

For example, I have a `var x = "y"`, (example variable for easier understanding) and I would like to edit a key in `servers.json` by the name of `y`, however, when I specify `servers.x`, it edits the key `'x'`, instead of `'y'`. Of course, this is expected, there is nothing wrong with this, however I don't know how I can use the variables contents as the key name. Here is my code for easier understanding:

```
const servers = require('./servers.json');
var x = "y";
servers.x = "blah";
```

I would like my servers.json file to look like this:

```
{"y" : "blah"}
```

Instead it looks like this:

```
{"x" : "blah"}
```

How can I use the variable x's contents as the key name?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can use ["object name"] instead

```
const servers = require('./servers.json');
var x = "y";
servers[x] = "blah";
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

`servers[x] = "blah";`

You are welcome

Comment: Wow, surprisingly easy! Thanks again :)